# Too vs Either in agreement of negative sentences

Tags: adverbs

> SAM: I don’t like choclates.
>
> BOB: 1) I **too**, don’t like choclates. (Or) 2)I don’t like choclates, **either**.

What would be the correct sentence of Bob, Sentence1 or Sentence2?

If anyone sentence of bob is wrong why is it wrong?

Comment: (2) is correct. If Bob was being very formal he could say "I, too, _dislike_ chocolates" (note spelling).

Comment: @KateBunting So why is “I too don’t like choclates” wrong? What does it mean?

Comment: It's not that it means anything different, it's just that when the thing we're 'agreeing' with is negative, we say "I don't either" and not "I don't, too". And it's 'choc**o**lates'!